# Enviar mensajes de manera automática a whatsapp desde excel

Tags: excel

Hola a todos pues como dice el titulo de mi pregunta, quiero enviar mensajes a whatsapp desde excel, logro abrir la pagina de whatsapp web con el teléfono que quiero enviarle el mensaje, pero lo que quiero es que el proceso sea automático, ya que la manera que los tengo tengo que confirmar para enviar el mensaje y volver a dar click al botón de enviar.
Si alguien sabe de alguna manera que sea automática que lo agradezco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que no tengas que hacer manualmente la acción de "Enviar", lo que podes hacer es usar un `SendKey` desde la macros para que se oprima "Enter" y se envíe sólo.

```
ActiveWindow.Application.SendKeys "(~)"
```

Esto lo que hace es "simular" el Enter, entonces se enviaría el mensaje.

Saludos!